# Nikon d70 "This Card Cannot Be Used" Error with Compact Flash

Tags: nikon, compactflash, nikon-d70

So I just bought this card and it is on the compatibility list from Nikon. It isn't corrupt. I was able to format it properly. I also was able to do a firmware update from the card to the camera to bring it to the latest version of 2.0.

When I take a picture I get the error as stated in the title. There is no common error messages other than that one that is on the LCD screen.

Any help?

Comment: Are you able to format it _in camera_?

Comment: yes it formats it to fat and i do a chdsk /F on it and it is okay

Comment: I am using the Lexar 2gb CF disk

Comment: I have contacted Nikon, Lexar, BHphoto and none of them can solve the problem. Most of them are tech people though...

Comment: Did you buy it from B&H Photo? I'd just ask for an exchange. I'd suspect a counterfeit card, but B&H has a good enough reputation that that'd make me quite surprised.

Comment: I'll contact them again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incompatibilities between certain batches of memory cards and cameras occasionally pop up. Unless the camera maker issues a firmware update to work around the issue with the card,¹ about the only alternative is to use another card that does not have the same issue with a particular camera. The replacement card could even be another example of the "same" card from a different batch with 'silent' updates made by the card manufacturer to fix the issue.

Your best course of action is to contact the seller of the card and see if they will allow you to exchange it for another card. Give them as much detailed information as you can about the issue. If they are a large seller of memory cards, such as B&H mentioned in your comment to the question, they'll probably have examples of each model card from several different batch numbers. Explaining the issue and letting them know your desire to exchange your card for one from a different batch number will increase the chances that the replacement card will work with your camera. If the issue remains with the replacement card, it's probably time to consider going with a different card model altogether.

You can also check to see if your Nikon D70 is running the latest firmware revision. It is doubtful that Nikon has issued any firmware updates for the D70 in quite a while, but that's no guarantee that your particular D70 is currently running the last version that was released.

---

¹It is extremely rare for camera makers to issue firmware updates due to issues that are usually the responsibility of the card makers, but it has happened a few times.

When Canon introduced the EOS 1D X Mark II it was the first camera they offered with a CFast card slot. At the time one of the only CFast cards on the market from a "top tier" memory card brand were sold by SanDisk. Unfortunately, many of the affected CFast cards were provided by Canon and sold in promotional bundles with the camera when it was introduced. It turned out there was a glitch in the SanDisk implementation of the CFast standard. This resulted in the last images (usually a single raw file or the last 2-3 jpegs) shot before turning off the 1D X Mark II that were recorded to certain early SanDisk CFast cards being corrupted. The last shot(s) before the camera went into 'standby' mode were also affected.

Even though the issue was the result of [issues in the SanDisk cards](https://www.digitaltrends.com/photography/sandisk-corrupts-images-from-canon-1-dx-mark-ii/), Canon quickly issued a [firmware update that included a workaround to resolve the issue](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/product-advisories/detail/service%20notice%20eos-1d%20x%20mark%20ii%20%20image%20corruption%20with%20some%20sandisk%20cfast%20cards/!ut/p/z1/hZLfboIwFMafZQ_QnNKyApeAGNxkigqjvVkaK9pM_gSM295-1Zglhsh6d5Lf-fqd8x0QUICo5Vnv5Uk3tTyamgv2kaSxG89CPF9sXgPsR8FiTdmE4pDC-xXAD56PQdz1T0mE_WSTzxM6o3jFbv0jgBj_PwceAC9Xy_aQDsQGtBj3-vKfW7MO0iVhsgfRytMB6bpsoNjKatfJHgrVHzsodk2PLIW-USW7T6S1sSXuhfHKc7DPJiz23gI8S58HQB7YBvAmISXTi7kbMOKdm9mdh7MTk9RZ774gq5uuMsGuL4rtVivgzhYTWzkuUk4pkS0JQZ5yGFIWtS3pYpcqBvFwO8NbCP-SEBa0VZbVP0jwZRuVSURtkT79Aqaf7Ds!/dz/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/) and allow users of 1D X Mark II cameras to use the affected cards. Subsequent CFast cards from SanDisk, as well as other suppliers, do not cause the issue even when used in 1D X Mark II cameras with the original, pre-patched firmware version.

Comment: I did upgrade right away... the funny thing is i used the same CF card to do it...

Comment: @ChrisZog By 'upgrade' do you mean the firmware? Or something else?

Comment: yes that is what i mean

Comment: Have you formatted the card *with the camera*, or only on your computer?

Comment: I did both......